# Каким образом инициализировать свойство массива в Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Каким образом инициализировать свойство массива в Kotlin?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_payment")
data class PaymentEntity(
        **@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)**
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
        var user: User? = null) {
}
```

Comment: @ManyToOne(cascade = arrayOf(javax.persistence.CascadeType.DETACH))

Answer (score 2):

Современный синтаксис использует ограниченный литерал массива:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "t_payment")
data class PaymentEntity(
        @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.DETACH])
        @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
        var user: User? = null) {
}
```